# Workbox not working on localhost but it works on 127.0.0.1

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I created a project with `workbox-webpack-plugin`, when it runs on `127.0.0.1:8080`, requests load my `service-worker.js` and it is working,like this:
[image]

But when it runs on `localhost:8080`, requests doesn't load my `service-worker.js`, just load `manifest.json`. 
What's happend? Is this normal?

```
workboxOptions: {
    importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
    clientsClaim: true,
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: new RegExp('^http://localhost:8080/'),
        // Defaults to `networkFirst` if omitted
        handler: 'cacheFirst',
        options: {
          cacheName: 'my-app-cache',
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 10,
            maxAgeSeconds: 300
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the console log using Chrome developer tools in order to find whats going wrong with your service worker.  Its importat to take in count that service workers only run on under https or over the loopback ipv4 address (127.0.0.1).  Also, check if your host is resolving 127.0.0.1 from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error with WebPack 4. The issue for me was I had `eval-inline-sources` on top of 5MiB of javascript, which exploded to over 20MiB of code WebPack for some reason couldn't handle caching that and `(failed) net::NET_ERROR`

My solution was to switch to true `source-map`s, it wasn't noticeably slower and solved the problem. They have might have it in the fetchWrapper.js on newer versions, but since Workbox 5, files larger than 2MiB get excluded from prefetch anyway.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/